# Moodle Turnitin: add functionality to insert extra text in assignments

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, moodle

Some universities have a Blue Card scheme enabling students with specific learning difficulties (SpLDs) to flag their work with a blue card, so the tutor will mark it with due consideration.

We needed a way of making it easier for students to flag their work with a blue card, and I have come up with the following script, which goes into the Additional HTML section in Site Administration in Moodle, and works with the Turnitin plugin. (See my other post for a [script that works with the Moodle Assignment functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536020/moodle-assignment-functionality-to-insert-extra-text-in-assignments/).)

First the student clicks the button to add the blue card, which inserts the text "Blue Card: " at the start of the assignment title. When the form is submitted, the JavaScript looks for the text "Blue Card" on the next page, colours the table cell blue and appends a link to the dyslexia marking guidelines.

Comment: Here are some screenshots of what it looks like
http://obis-insights.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/using-blue-card-on-moodle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var TurnitinBlueCardButton =  '<input type="button" id="tiibluecard" value="Flag with Blue Card"/> <a href="http://www.brookes.ac.uk/students/wellbeing/dyslexia-spld/blue-marking-cards/" class="info" target="_blank" title="What is the Blue Card scheme?">What\'s this?</a><br/>'

/* TURNITIN BLUE CARD */
if (!document.getElementById('fitem_id_submissiontype')) {
   /* do nothing */
} else {
    document.getElementById('fitem_id_submissiontype').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', TurnitinBlueCardButton);
}

/* EVENT LISTENER FOR TURNITIN BLUE CARD BUTTON */
if (!document.getElementById('tiibluecard')) {
   /* do nothing */
} else {
    document.getElementById("tiibluecard").addEventListener('click', function () {  
        var title = document.getElementById('id_submissiontitle');
        /* turn off validation of title field, as it will now have a value */
        title.removeAttribute('onchange');
        if (!title.value) {
            title.value = ('Blue Card: '); 
         } else {
            title.value = ('Blue Card: ' + title.value);
         }
    });
}

/* highlight blue card in TURNITIN submission inbox table */
if (!document.getElementById('inboxTable')) {
   /* do nothing */
} else {
     var table = document.getElementById('inboxTable');
     var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
     var cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');

     for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
         if (cells[i].innerHTML.includes('Blue Card')){
             cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#99ccff';
             cells[i].innerHTML += ' [<a href="http://www.brookes.ac.uk/students/wellbeing/dyslexia-spld/blue-marking-cards/" class="info" target="_blank" title="What is the Blue Card scheme?">What\'s this?</a>]';
        }
   }
}
</script>
```

**NB: code is supplied 'as is' without any commitment to it being fit for purpose and is also supplied without any commitment to maintenance or support.**

([also posted on our team blog](http://obis-insights.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/turnitin-moodle-blue-card.html))

UPDATE: in order to get this to work in Internet Explorer 11, I had to change a couple of things:

```
/* highlight blue card in TURNITIN submission inbox table */
if (!document.getElementById('inboxTable')) {
   /* do nothing */
} else {
     var table = document.getElementById('inboxTable');
     var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
     var cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');

     for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
         if (cells[i].innerText.search('Blue Card') > -1){
             cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#99ccff';
             cells[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ' [<a href="http://www.brookes.ac.uk/staff/academic/dyslexia-spld-service/marking-work/" class="info" target="_blank" title="What is the Blue Card scheme?">What\'s this?</a>]');
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Tested in IE (Edge), Chrome, Firefox, on Windows, and Safari on iPhone 5